# Python sendmail() returns {} despite including emails that don't exist

Tags: python, email

I was experimenting sending emails using python and `smtplib`. I am aware that if the email was sent to all email addresses then `sendmail()` returns {}. But I intentionally added 2 email addresses (bbbbbbbbbb@gmail.com and ccccccccccccc@gmail.com) that do not exist (I confirmed they don't exist by checking sent items in my gmail account) and still got an empty dictionary. Is something going wrong here?

```
import smtplib

smtpobj=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) #creating an SMTP object. 
smtpobj.ehlo() #saying hello to the server

smtpobj.starttls() #enabling encryption for the connection

password=str(input("Please enter your password: "))

smtpobj.login('thereallasad@gmail.com', password) #logging in to account

lst=['govindsomadas@gmail.com', 'thereallasad@gmail.com', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb@gmail.com','ccccccccccccccccc@gmail.com']

smtpobj.sendmail('thereallasad@gmail.com', lst, 'Subject: Testing\nDear Govind,\n\nThanks for creating me.\n\nRegards,\nLasad')

print(smtpobj.sendmail('thereallasad@gmail.com', lst, 'Subject: Testing\nDear Govind,\n\nThanks for creating me.\n\nRegards,\nLasad'))

smtpobj.quit() #disconnects from smtp server
```

Comment: I think there will be no output even if the mail-address does not exist. What outputs do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It will return an empty dictionary if even one of the email addresses worked, if none works then it raises an exception.
Try sending an email to all the wrong emails.